# Language switch redirect to homepage or content page

Tags: navigation, cms, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Language switch redirect to homepage or content page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/language-switch-redirect-to-homepage-or-content-page)

I'm using a CMS that supports multiple languages and the build-in SEO tools are decent.

The problem is that it doesn't support switching between languages and stay on the same page because it's the creators opinion that content can be different between languages so languages aren't interlinked.

From a user experience point of view I think this is bad but what are your opinions?
Is a redirect to the homepage when switching languages ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to be posted to [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

However, I think you should try to step into your users' shoes. If they click on the *change language* button (or whatever interface is used), are they expecting to be redirected to the homepage? I think in most cases, they probably expect to see a translation of the current page. To make this more clear, you could label the button "translate this page to: ...".

The creators are probably right in not assuming that all pages will have a translation, and different locales' substite will have different content. However, unless this is the general case, and only a few pages are shared across all the different subsites, I would redirect to the corresponding page by default.

So I guess it depends on whether your users view your property as a network of sites in different languages or a single site that has been translated to different languages.

Comment: I'm sorry, I came to this subforum from a google search. I will post it in UX!

Comment: @Simon: I'd vote to close it so that it'd be migrated to UX, but UX isn't listed as one of the migrate options. Hopefully someone with more rep than me can manually migrate it or otherwise you could double-post and maybe they'll merge them.